# What is this expression means? $\sin^{-2}x$

Tags: trigonometry

I know this is very silly question but I didn't know how to research it in google. Please bare with me on this one. I have two thoughts:

> $$\sin^{-2}x = \frac{1}{\sin^2x}$$

I think this cannot be possible. Or is it:

> $$\sin^{-2}x = \arcsin^2x$$

I didn't make up this question, I mean kinda. I am developing an android application which solves mathematical equations for demonstration purposes. I was brainstorming what the user can input, I came up with this expression.

Comment: "I think this cannot be possible" Why?

Comment: Could be both. It's bad notation. You have to guess by context.

Comment: The first one is correct. But do answer Michael's question

Comment: Because if this can be possible, then sin powered to -1 wouldn't be arcsin. I think that way.

Comment: @Bora "sin powered to -1 wouldn't be arcsin" $f^{-1}$ is notation for inverse function, do you know?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I know. But I was talking according to my question. I was talking about "if not" posible.

Comment: @Bora Anyway, $\sin^{-2} x \ne \arcsin^2 x$ because it means that $1/\sin x = \arcsin x$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: Some people use $\sin^{-1} x$ to mean $\arcsin x$, that's the point.

Comment: @Javier, I know it.

Comment: The problem is that $f^n(x)$ could means $(f(x))^n$ or $$(\underbrace{f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f }_{n \text{ times }}) (x) $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a computer application, I would suggest you avoid all ambiguity by forcing the user to type
$$
(\sin x)^2
$$
for $\sin^2(x)$, and
$$
\arcsin x
$$
for the inverse function. Don't allow $\sin^n (x)$ as it is abusive shorthand which has done more to confuse people than help.

However, it's also worth noting that Wolfram Alpha interprets [$\sin^{-2}(x) = \frac{1}{(\sin x)^2}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E-2%28x%29), whereas [$\sin^{-1}(x) = \arcsin x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E-1%28x%29). More generally, it appears that $n = 1$ is a special case in $\sin^n(x)$ and otherwise it is interpreted as $(\sin x)^n$.

---

The reason $\sin^n(x)$ is bad notation for $(\sin x)^n$ is that in most contexts, $f^n(x)$ means the [$n$th iterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definition) of $f$.
In particular, the $-1$th iterate of an invertible function is the inverse,
so $\sin^{-1}$ would actually be a natural way to denote $\arcsin$.

On the other hand, the problem with $\sin^{-1}(x)$ for $\arcsin$ is of course that it conflicts with the hugely widespread notation $\sin^2(x)$.
You really can't win.

Comment: +1, though I disagree that $f^n(x)$ means the nth iterate in every other context. In abstract algebra it's a common notion (as usually $f^n$ refers to $\underbrace{f\cdot f\cdot f\cdots f}_{n\text{ dots}}$, and the operation $\cdot$ is simply composition), but not in other circumstances. I've seen $\ln^n(x)$, for example, and $J_n^m(x)$ very often means the Bessel function of order $n$ raised to the $m$th power. The alternative notation for the nth iterate of $f$, $f^{\circ\ n}(x)$, isn't that universal either however. It's best just to state the definition of $f^n$ in context.

Comment: $\sin(x)^n$ please.

Comment: @user3002473 That's a good point. But $f^{-1}$ very universally means inverse, I think. Whenever I see $f^n$ at least for a general function $f$ I assume it means iterate. Anyway I'll update my answer to make the wording a little less strong.

Comment: @6005 Yeah true, I've never heard of a context where $f^{-1} = 1/f$. Historically, that makes wonder if the notation $f^n$ started in abstract algebra so that $f^{-1}$ clearly indicates the inverse, and then other fields borrowed from that.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you found this in a book, paper, or web page, without an explanation, that is a bad book, paper or web page.

(2)  Do not use this notation yourself.